# Custom Rails Validation - multiple fields simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm looking to create a custom validation in Rails.  I need to validate that a POSTed start_date_time and end_date_time (together) do not overlap that combination in the database.

Example:

### In the database:

```
start_date
  05/15/2000
end_date
  05/30/2000
```

### POSTed:

```
start_date
  05/10/2000
end_date
  05/20/2000
FAILS!
```

Here's the rub:

1) I want to send *both* start and end fields into the function

2) I want to get the values of *both* POSTed fields to use in building a query.

3) Bonus: I want to use a scope (like say, for a given [:user_id, :event] -- but, again, I want that to be passed in.

How do I get the values of the fields?

### Let's say my function looks like this:

```
def self.validates_datetime_not_overlapping(start, finish, scope_attr=[], conf={})
    config = {
        :message => 'some default message'
    }
    config.update(conf)

    # Now what?
end
```

I'm sort of stuck at this point.  I've scoured the net, and can't figure it out....  I can get the *value* of *either* start *or* finish, but not both **at the same time** by using validate_each ...

*Any* help would be *great*!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the idea to check the start and end date of the record being validated against the start and end dates of all existing records in the database?

Comment: Yes.... with the addition of a scope.

Comment: And you want to write it as a reusable `validates_datetime_not_overlapping` rather than just overriding `validate`? Are `start` and `finish` parameters the names of the attributes containing the dates?

Comment: reusable: yes
start/finish - names of attrs: yes (therefore dynamic...)
the scope will also be dynamic

Answer (score 3):

What about [custom validation methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods)?

You can add:

```
validate :check_dates

def check_dates
  do.whatever.you.want.with.any.field
end
```

EDIT:

So maybe [`validate_with`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_with)?

Modified example from RoR Guides:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with DatesValidator, :start => :your_start_date, :stop => :your_stop_date
end

class DatesValidator < ActiveRecord::Validator
  def validate
    start = record.send(options[:start])
    stop  = record.send(options[:stop])

    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: The trick here is that I will not know beforehand the *name* of the fields that I want to work with. I want this abstract so that I can just send the names in the validation call.  Make sense?

Comment: Validations are run when you save object and then you can't send any parameter. So I think that you want to create somethig like `validate_my_date_fields :start_date, :finish_date` that only takes two arguments and then fire some method that will check it?

Comment: I may have to try this new EDIT you suggest....  I'll get back to you.

(THANKS)...

Comment: OK... Apparently this method is Rails 3.  I'm on 2.3.8.  IS there a way to do this with 2.3.8?

Many thanks!